# How can I change which commit is master in sourcetree?

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

I want to change master to be at the commit "Local settings for Jakov". Then I want to delete the two latest commits, "Import xlsxwriter" and "Revert "Import xlsxwriter". Is this possible?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Right click over that commit "Local settings for Jakov". And then choose the option "Reset master to this commit"

[image: Example]